# List custom post type with certain tag (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, tags, custom-post-type

So this has been driving me nuts.

I can easily list all post titles that have a certain tag, like this:

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'tag=products' );
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo "<h1>" . the_title() . "</h1>";
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But this is just for all standard posts. What I need to do instead if make this work for a certain custom post type only (my custom post type is called 'products'). In other words, it should display the titles of all 'products' custom post types that also have the tag 'webonly'.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **display all list of post which in add webonly tag**
>
> ```
> notice-tag = your tag taxonomy name
>
> terms in define your tag slug name
>
> 'post_type'=>'notice',  in define your post type
> ```

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'notice-tag',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => array( 'webonly' )
                        )
                ),
            'post_type'=>'notice',
            'order'=>'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
    query_posts($args); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php echo the_title(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Bingo. Just needed to reset the query at the end and now it's all good. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer. In the above query, 'post_type' is ignored. If you remove "tax_query", then 'post_type' is not ignored.